# Each Key Stroke causes Editor to Reset

Tags: ssas, mdx, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

This issue doesn't seem to present itself unless the project has been open for a while. It is usually open for a while due to development occurring on a remote desktop.

While editing calculations in the cube, every time I hit a key, the editor jumps to the first calculation in the script. Often this happens and creates a situation where there is an incomplete calculation or new calculation, and it throws the error that I have to edit the MDX in the Script View instead of the Form View.

Any ideas on other than Save/Re-open?

Comment: I hit this occasionally and feel your pain. Restarting Visual Studio seems to resolve it usually. Does it for you? I know that's not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Raise an issue on connect describing it and it might get fixed